# lock screen elapsed time continues when paused Swift 3

Tags: time, controls, lockscreen, pause

When I pause my music on the lock screen it stops the elapsed time on the number but when I press play again it jumps up with the time it was paused added on. I tried setting the rat to 0 on pause but that just makes the whole time disappear.

does anyone have any other info on this?

Comment: I've got the same problem .. have you found any solution ?

Comment: I did i added a second timer and then when i pressed pause i used timer2?.invalidate()
  timer2 = nil and when i press play i set timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateLabel), userInfo:
    nil, repeats: true)  // create a timer to update your label
   
    timeLabel.text = "-\(dateStringFromTimeInterval(vox.duration - vox.currentTime))"  I am fairly new to programming so I hope this helps you but setting a second timer and then setting the time to equal music duration minus music elapsed worked for me.

Comment: @FaridAlHaddad I also added this to the lock screen functions where you declared the the play functions in the locked screen....MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: self.vox.duration,
    MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: self.vox.currentTime]....vox being your music

Comment: The problem is everytime i give the MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration a new value, it resets to 0 (even if the value is not 0)